# what is different between style vs styles in component - fluentui/react-northstar

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am using [fluentui/react-northstar](https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.60.0/)
as in the doc, **styles** has below definition

```
Name    Default Type         Description  

styles  ComponentSlotStyle   Additional CSS styles to apply to the component instance.
```

but what is different between **style** vs **styles** in  component.

```
<Flex styles={{ marginTop: 15 }}> </Flex> 

<Flex style={{ marginTop: 15 }}> </Flex>
```

Answer (score 0):

`style` is a prop provided by `react` for all HTML elements (same as style attribute in HTML)

`styles` is a prop provided for components that accept `IStyleableComponentProps`, which provides additional functionality over the style attribute like theming.